# Bootstrap wrapper div does not rap sub divs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want a 2 column layout with every odd row a different color.

```
        <?php
            $line = "even";
            foreach($number as $key => $value){
                $line = ($line == "even")? "odd" : "even";
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 <?php echo $line ?>">
                    <div class='col-sm-11 no_padding pat-info'><h5><?php echo $key ?></h5></div>
                    <div class='col-sm-1 no_padding pat-info '><h5><?php echo $value ?></h5></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

The logic here is fine I think, but the styling and Bootstrap stumps me.

This is what I get

[image]

The wrapper `col-md-12` divs are all squashed up at the top and their content shows like it should.

Why is this?

Comment: add a proper `<div class="row"..>` whenever you want to add `<div class"col..>`..

Comment: @BagusTesa yep. thanks. add a answer and I will mark it.